# How to spilt the 10000 records in batch using PHP

Tags: php

I  need to split more than 10,000 records into 50 records in each batch.

I have the  `$name_arr[]`. This array have more than 10,000 records. How can I split  this array into fifty record for each batch.

How can I do. Please help me.

Comment: You can use array-chunk if you want to split an array into multiple arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
array_chunk($name_arr, 50);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Ok, I have  to  insert all 10000 records with 2 mins.